# firebase-admin Filter.or only considers first where clause

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have `parties` documents that have an `author` and a `users` map.  I'm trying to query for all the documents that are authored by the user, or have the user in the `users` map.

The issue is that the following code only considers the `usersPath != null` clause in the `or` condition, and I don't know why:

```js
const getParties = onCall({}, async (request) => {
  const userPath = new FieldPathAdmin("users", request.auth.token.email);
  return dbAdmin
    .collection("parties")
    .where(
      Filter.or(
        Filter.where(userPath, "!=", null),
        Filter.where("author.uid", "==", request.auth.uid)
      )
    )
    .get();
}
```

If I swap those `where` clauses, then it only considers the `author.uid == request.auth.uid` clause.

Imports and setup:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase-admin";
import { getFirestore, Filter, FieldPath } from "firebase-admin/firestore";
import { onCall } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
const app = initializeApp({...});
```

A parties doc looks like:

```json
{
  author: {
    uid: "foo-bar"
    ...
  },
  users: {
    example@test.com: {
      uid: "quux-baz"
      email: "example@test.com",
      joinedAt: 1705951291621
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

NOTE: I'm using the `firebase-admin` package instead of `firebase` because this is on a node server using callable functions, not the browser client.

firebase-admin version 11.9.0

Comment: We can't see where `request.auth.token.email` is coming from, as there is no `request` visible to us.  Are you sure that expression has the value you expect?  Maybe you could hard code it into your query instead of depending on a variable, then edit the question to show us the new code and results?

Comment: Are you sure you have the required indexes for the query: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview?

Comment: For example, before I add an index I get this error message: `The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/project-8080059325282098184/firestore/indexes?create_composite=Clxwcm9qZWN0cy9wcm9qZWN0LTgwODAwNTkzMjUyODIwOTgxODQvZGF0YWJhc2VzLyhkZWZhdWx0KS9jb2xsZWN0aW9uR3JvdXBzLzc3ODQ5NDIxL2luZGV4ZXMvXxABGgcKA3VpZBABGhwKGHVzZXJzLmBleGFtcGxlQHRlc3QuY29tYBABGgwKCF9fbmFtZV9fEAE`. If you click that, you'll see that it requires an index on the specific combination of field that you query for **including** the subfield with the user's email address

Comment: @DougStevenson I should have mentioned that the `request` variable comes from the onCall function which just makes a firebase callable server function: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd

I edited the post to show this.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I haven't set up any custom indexes for this yet, but I would be surprised if that's the issue since the query works successfully if the `usersPath != null` clause is first in the `or` order.  It gets all the parties that a user has been invited to.  (Could I make a separate document for each user that lists all the parties they're invited to?  Yes, but then I'd have the same issue trying to fetch all the users that are invited to a single party.  It's a many-to-many relationship.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're missing the composite index that is required for your query. But I also think you have an anti-pattern here, as you'll need to define an index for every `users.<email>` value - which won't scale.

Instead of checking the map field for whether a specific child exists in there, I recommend adding an array field that holds just the email values you want to query on:

```
userEmails: ["example@test.com"]
```

Now you only need a single index (on `userEmails`, which is automatically defined) to find the correct documents - and you can then continue to read the user's data from the `users/{email}` map you already have.

Comment: Can an index be made on the contents of the array?  So that I can query for all the parties that a user is invited to?

Comment: Yup. See the docs on [querying for array membership](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) for more on this.